# Ok to create UIView on background thread?

Tags: ios

OK, normally I know it's not ok. But what if I know I'll never attach that view to the actual UI hierarchy - it's only used to generate a snapshot, or compute something, or whatever.

If it IS ok, how do I silence the `Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread` console dump? (that console output is the reason I'm paranoid about doing this in the first place, now).

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I know I'll never attach that view to the actual UI hierarchy

I don’t think it matters what you know. The main thread checker presumably knows more. In the interface or not, UIKit interface objects are *inherently* not threadsafe. Do this on the main thread.

Comment: "Not threadsafe" doesn't inherently mean "must only be called on the main thread". Or does it? I thought it meant that it's not safe to interleave calls on different threads. But if it's all in the same (background) thread? Could there be global resources being accessed, that are indeed also accessed from the 'actual ui' views, that my background view will also access?